How can I make a data randomly like form of LaTeX
This is a data in LaTeX, I input by my hand.
7&9&9&10&9&10&7&8&10&8\\
6&7&9&9&10&10&10&9&9&9\\
8&8&7&9&9&9&9&9&9&8\\
9&9&8&10&9&10&7&6&9&9\\


How can I make a table containt 10 columns and 3 rows  randomly like form of LaTeX by Mathematica.
a&b&c&d&e&&f&g&h&k\\
a&b&c&d&e&&f&g&h&k\\
8&8&7&9&9&9&9&9&9&8\\
9&9&8&10&9&10&7&6&9&9\\

I think about
Clear["Global`*"]
Table[{a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a}, {a, 5, 9}, {b, 2, 5}, {c, 4, 7}];
Flatten[%, 2]


Why not RandomInteger[100, {3, 10}] which gives random matrix of 3 rows and 10 columns,. You can change the 100 to any other value you want. see help

I tried RandomInteger[10, {3, 10}], I got {{2, 9, 9, 2, 5, 5, 8, 3, 8, 4}, {0, 7, 7, 6, 2, 0, 8, 8, 2, 9}, {5,    8, 8, 9, 7, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5}}, How can I replace , to &, in each element?

How can I replace , to & That is what TeXForm does automatically. I thought you knew about TeXForm

Thank you very much. I know about TeXForm.

TeXForm[RandomInteger[10, {3, 10}]]


